# Can NAT capable modem/router be linked for failover?

Tags: networking, nat, failover

There are a total of 7 systems on the network. The network has evolved from two small shops (3-4 computers each) to a single one with a sum total of 7 systems. Historically there were two ISP (which the new management would like to continue).

Thus there are two NAT enabled devices at the last-mile from each ISP

- Belkin F7D1301
- Baton iBLR6111A

Networking is almost an unknown to me. An ipconfig on the computers in the network brought the realization there are 2 sub-nets ... atleast it looks like there are 2 sub-nets (192.168.1.x, and 192.168.2.x).

My gut tells me the above mentioned modem/router cannot be connected & configured to be used transparently for the computers connected to the other modem/router without additional hardware. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Choppy at best but if the new management doesn't wish to network with the hosts using the other connection, it will work.

What you need is a simple dual wan router that can handle something like that. Ideally, you would get rid of those NAT devices and opt for a basic modem to avoid LARGE headaches and very slow connections. Most of the dual WAN routers support failover.

Comment: Sounds like a solution; I'll toss the idea upstairs. Thanks a tonne!
Could I hit on you for an alternative too please? Will a dual NIC on one of the boxes serve, do you think?